# Disabling Several Submit Buttons, Leaving Just One Enabled (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, submit, disabled-input

I have a number of similar forms on a page, created by a PHP while loop. Each form has about 10 text inputs and a submit button. If (just for this question) the forms are called A, B, C and D, I want to disable the submit buttons on B, C and D when one of the inputs on A is in focus. And likewise for each of the other forms.

My thought for doing this is to have two lines of jQuery. The first line will disable all the submit buttons. The second line wil re-enable the one with the focus on the input. I can do the first part of that but I am stuck with the second part.

Each form is

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="changeform">
```

and each submit button is

```
<input name="changebutton" type="submit" value="Change">
```

Then my script is

```
$("input").focus(function(){
$('input[name="changebutton"]').prop('disabled', true); 
$(this).closest('form').find('input[name="changebutton"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Line 2 works fine (all the buttons are disabled) but line 3 does nothing.

I have tried using line 3 to put in a big red border (so I can see what part of the page is being affected) and nothing shows at all.

I have tried using .closest('table').find('td') and that works. So it looks as though something in the this/closest/find bit is not working properly.

Comment: Can you give your complete HTML structure? If i put this in a fiddle it works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/frv47vk7/

Comment: Your code seems just fine to me. And its working.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere on the page. Both my original solution and Mangesh Parte's below now work. There was a conflict between the form tags and the table structure.
Thanks to you both for taking the trouble to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parents()` function here.
Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2fo2bL8/)

```
$("input").focus(function(){
   $('input[name="changebutton"]').prop('disabled', true); 
   $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="changebutton"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```